# Как распарсить строку на id, имя, цену и количество

Tags: java, строки, парсер

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputLine;
        try {
            inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String product = "198478  Шорты хоккейные 173.00  17 ";
            String[] productArray = product.split(" ");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(inputLine,true);
            if (args[0].equals("-c productName price quantity")) {
                fileWriter.write(product);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как распарсить строку `product` по количеству символов, чтобы из этой строки получить id, имя, цену и количество.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что означает "по количеству символов"?

Comment: productName - название товара, 30 символов.
price - цена, 8 символов.
quantity - количество, 4 символа. Примерно вот так

Comment: это не имеет ничего общего с "распарсить", гугли "ява подстрока" и бери подстроки по нужным индексам

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо.

Comment: @СемёнБарышников Подстроки ты не сможешь вычислить, поскольку требуется задать два значения - начальный индекс и конечный, а этого вычислить в твоём коде невозможно ;)

Comment: И что тогда делать?

Comment: @RomanC если брать как указано фиксированной длины "название товара, 30 символов. price - цена, 8 символов. quantity - количество, 4 символа", то ничего вычислять не надо. Если длина переменная, то фиксированные подстроки не подойдут, конечно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Для того, чтобы брать подстроку, нужно указывать индекс первого элемента, фиксированной длины тут недостаточно ;)

Comment: @СемёнБарышников Нужно вычислить *нужные*  индексы (как сказал @Эникейщик) значений полей, ну и потом можно брать подстроки по фиксированной длине, которая не может быть больше чем настоящая длина ;)

Comment: @RomanC Так для строк фиксированной длины все это известно. Индекс первого элемента первой подстроки - 0. Индекс первого элемента второй подстроки = индес первого элемента первой подстроки + длина первой подстроки. И т.д.

Comment: строка имеет ровно 50 символов всегда.

Comment: @СемёнБарышников Тогда почему у тебя в коде длина строки равна 35?

Comment: @СемёнБарышников В вашем примере длина строки 35 символов

Comment: @Эникейщик Ты забыл туда добавить ещё пробелы после длины первой подстроки, и если он будет брать по фиксированной длине подстроки, то явно будет наезжать на другие поля. Тут нужно писать некий алгоритм прохода по символам и вычисления индексов, к сожалению нет времени этим заниматься. Не будешь же ставить формат CSV, и потом открывать библиотеку как на проде ;

Answer (score 1):

Можно разработать формат в виде регулярного выражения (в том числе с именованными группами) и получить необходимые данные из строки согласно этого формата.

Вариант решения с использованием кортежа (record) представлен ниже:

- создаётся кортеж (вместо него может быть обычный POJO-класс с конструктором, геттерами, методом `toString` и т.д.)
- создаётся шаблон строки с именованными группами `id`, `name`, `price`, `quantity`, имена групп записываются в угловых скобках
- входная строка проверяется на равенство `null` и соответствие шаблону

  - `(?<id>\\d+)` - `id`: 1 и более цифр, используем `Long` для длинных артикулов
  - `(?<name>\\p{L}.*\\S)` - `name`: начинается с любой буквы `\\p{L}`, заканчивается не-пробелом `\\S`
  - `(?<price>\\d+\\.\\d{2})` - `price`: цена с обязательными копейками
  - `(?<quantity>\\d+)` - `quantity`: количество, шт.
- если шаблон совпал, числовые компоненты парсятся при помощи соответствующих методов `Long.parseLong`, `Double.parseDouble`, `Integer.parseInteger`
- цену следует выражать в целых копейках

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    record Product(long id, String name, int price, int quantity) {}

    private static final Pattern PRODUCT_FORMAT = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<id>\\d+)\\s+(?<name>\\p{L}.*\\S)\\s+(?<price>\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\s+(?<quantity>\\d+)\\s*"
    );

    public static Product parseProduct(String str) {
        if (null != str) {
            Matcher m = PRODUCT_FORMAT.matcher(str);
            if (m.matches()) {
                return new Product(
                    Long.parseLong(m.group("id")), 
                    m.group("name"), 
                    (int)(Double.parseDouble(m.group("price")) * 100), // цена в целых копейках/центах
                    Integer.parseInt(m.group("quantity"))
                );
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вариант без именованных групп выглядит так (нумерация групп в шаблоне начинается с 1, так как `group(0)` возвращает целиком всю строку, совпавшую с шаблоном):

```java
private static final Pattern PRODUCT_FORMAT_SHORT = Pattern.compile(
    "(\\d+)\\s+(\\p{L}.*\\S)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\s+(\\d+)\\s*"
);

public static Product parseProduct2(String str) {
    if (null != str) {
        Matcher m = PRODUCT_FORMAT_SHORT.matcher(str);
        if (m.matches()) {
            return new Product(
                Long.parseLong(m.group(1)), 
                m.group(2),
                (int)(Double.parseDouble(m.group(3)) * 100), // цена в целых копейках/центах
                Integer.parseInt(m.group(4))
            );
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Тест:

```java
public static void main(String ... args) {
    System.out.println(parseProduct("198478  Шорты хоккейные 173.00  17 "));
    System.out.println(parseProduct2("198478  Шорты хоккейные 173.00  17 "));

}
```

Результат одинаков:

```
Product[id=198478, name=Шорты хоккейные, price=17300, quantity=17]
Product[id=198478, name=Шорты хоккейные, price=17300, quantity=17]
```

---

Существует также класс [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) с методом для разбора строк [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-), который возвращает массив объектов, но пользоваться им сложнее, так как он учитывает локаль при вводе и выводе данных.

---

***Дополнение***

Если *гарантируется*, что входная строка и данные в ней имеют фиксированную ширину, то можно разбить строку на части, используя данные о ширине каждой "колонки", включающей пробелы-разделители:

```java
public static String[] parseFixedWidths(String str, int ... widths) {
    if (null != str) {
        String[] result = new String[widths.length];
        for (int i = 0, start = 0, n = str.length(); i < widths.length && start < n; i++) {
            result[i] = str.substring(start, Math.min(start += widths[i], n)).trim();
        }
        return result;
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

Данные для теста соответственно изменены:

```java
//              12345678123456789012345678901234567890123456781234 = 8 + 30 + 8 + 4 = 50
String fixed = "198478  Шорты хоккейные               173.00  17  ";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseFixedWidths(fixed, 8, 30, 8, 4)));
```

Результат:

```
[198478, Шорты хоккейные, 173.00, 17]
```

Затем полученные строки можно дополнительно преобразовать в нужные типы (`long`, `int` и т.п.)

Comment: Оу, нешибко понятно конечно. Буду разбираться. Спасибо

Comment: Что именно непонятно?

Comment: Именно record, да и регулярки такие не видел,  про  Matcher ничего не знаю.

Comment: record'ы (кортежи) появились в Java 14 как превью-фичи в 2020, официально вошли в язык в Java 16 в 2021.  Вместо них могут использоваться обычные классы, но тогда пришлось бы ещё писать конструктор/метод `toString`.  В регулярках можно использовать обычные группы (без имён), тогда пришлось бы обращаться по номеру группы, начиная с 1: `Long.parseLong(m.group(1))` и т.д., а сама регулярка "упрощается": `"(\\d+)\\s+(\\p{L}.*\\S)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\s+(\\d+)\\s*"`

Comment: @СемёнБарышников, смотрите дополнительный вариант для строк/колонок фиксированной длины